# How to get output of a python program with inputs, exactly same as running that program in command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess, user-input

I want to run a another python program(Let's say "code.py" to that program) with some inputs from my python code and get the inputs, output as a string exactly same as if I run that code.py in command line. Code in code.py file  is not static(Actually it contains some kind of python code from user which accepts inputs). But to explain my question, I use a code.py file with following code.

```
#code.py file
in1=input("in1: ")
in2=input("in2: ")
print("You entered",in1,in2)
```

After some searching I'm able to send inputs and get output from the code.py.

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
process=Popen(["python", "code.py"], stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)
out=process.communicate(input=b'Input1\nInput2\n')[0]
print(out.decode('UTF-8'))
```

But my problem is the output not exactly same as the text which display when I run that code.py in command line. (Inputs are also given by user, for convenience I have hard coded the inputs)

The output text of my code.

`in1: in2: You entered Input1 Input2`

The sting with input & output which I want

```
in1: Input1
in2: Input2
You entered Input1 Input2
```

Are there any way to get my expected output string ?